# Toggle editing on Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, editing, virtual-layer

When I'm adding a Virtual Layer to a project using QGIS 3.12.2, it cannot be toggled to edit mode. That is: the pencil icon is grey coloured. This can be said for layers created either by the `Create Virtual Layer` or the `DB Manager` SQL query.

Is it possible to edit a Virtual Layer? If so, how can it be done? If not, is there any documentation or reference regarding this aspect?

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) implies that it is not possible to edit a virtual layer by saying _Virtual layers do not carry data by themselves and can be seen as views_

Comment: IMHO ... Virtual Layer is not editable

Comment: it's all about being clear ... do u want to edit the **content** of the layer (=the result of the query) or edit the **definition** of the layer (=the query itself) which is of course possible ...

Comment: Hi @snaileater, I meant toggle editing the **content** of the virtual layer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can not edit a virtual layer this way. This is because a virtual layer is just a query on other layers. So you either need to edit the layers the virtual layer is based on, or save the virtual layer as a "static" file - once you have done this, you can edit that no-longer-virtual-layer.

You can only edit the query of this virtual layer.

Answer (score 9):

To complete the other answer

If you edit the source layer the virtual layer should update. 
If you use a database as a source you may create an editable view (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=editable%20view) for exemple) but keep in mind that you are still modifying the original data and not only the view.